# VS2015: Windows Mobile Extension for UWP v10586 missing

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2015

I have some odd issues with my Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. `Windows Mobile Extension for the UWP` v10586 is missing after an update of Visual Studio.

[image: Missing Mobile Extension for]

I already tried the following: uninstalling VS2015, repairing VS2015, modify and so on, but nothing fixed it.

What might cause the issue is **Windows Mobile Emulator 10586** in VS2015 setup. So far I did the following:

- **Deinstall** "Windows 10 for Mobile Image" in *System Control*
- **Modify** it in Visual Studio setup in *System Control* (like deselect it) ... it said it will remove it, but running the Modify setup again, it was ticked as available again.

Normally I wouldn't bother and just stick to v10240. So I set `Properties` -> `Target Version` to v10240 and selected only References with v10240. Did a `Clean` and a `Rebuild all` and even deleted the `bin` and `obj` folders, so there is no "old files" left. But starting the project reveals the following error:

> "Could not find Windows Runtime type
>   'Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons'.":"Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"

Which seems strange to me, as it is using the `Windows Mobile Extension for the UWP` v10240. Because if I remove it, it triggers errors of missing (mobile only) namespaces.

Does someone know a solution to the issue or a workaround on how to start and use v10240

Comment: have some problem on Windows 10 Technical Prewiev. And can't fix fix this problem too

Comment: Please see my solution below and tell me, if it was successful. This issue nearly made me go insane :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error and de- and reinstalling VS2015.2 and VS2015.3 I think what did the trick in the end was to deinstall `Emulators for Windows 10 Mobile` in System Control.

If you now do a repair or fresh install of VS2015 (current version) and in the setup screen `Emulators for Windows 10 Mobile` is not ticked as *already installed* then you are good to go, check it and you're done.

If you have no luck, like I did and installer said, it's still there, then the trick is to do the following: Download the `SDK` yourself [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and install it manually (it's quite fast) and then do a repair/install of VS2015 and then it's fixed (at least that was it for me).

I hope this helps others facing that weird problem.